# split a text line and create variable

Tags: python, text, formatting

I am a beginner with python and I try to use it to automate repetitive tasks. I'm struggling a lot with the following task: I have a bunch of text files formatted in the following way:
How could I from the following text lines:

```
Cluster -44 -58 +36  :
248 voxels (69%) covering 5% of atlas.sLOC l (Lateral Occipital Cortex, superior division Left)
51 voxels (14%) covering 5% of atlas.AG l (Angular Gyrus Left)
62 voxels (17%) covering 0% of atlas.not-labeled

Cluster -38 -84 +18  :
163 voxels (47%) covering 3% of atlas.sLOC l (Lateral Occipital Cortex, superior division Left)
49 voxels (14%) covering 0% of atlas.not-labeled

Cluster -42 -6 +30  :
89 voxels (34%) covering 2% of atlas.PreCG l (Precentral Gyrus Left)
1 voxels (0%) covering 0% of atlas.IFG oper l (Inferior Frontal Gyrus, pars opercularis Left)
```

create the following dataframe:

```
|x|y|z|voxels|voxels_pct|covering_pct|atlas|
|-|-|-|------|----------|------------|-----|
|-44 |-58 |+36|248|69|5|sLOC l (Lateral Occipital Cortex, superior division Left)|
|-44 |-58 |+36|51|14|5|AG l (Angular Gyrus Left)|
|-44 |-58 |+36|62|17|0|not-labeled|
|-38 |-84 |+18|163|34|3|sLOC l (Lateral Occipital Cortex, superior division Left)|
|-38 |-84 |+18|49|14|0|not-labeled|
|-42 |-6 |+30|89|34|2|PreCG l (Precentral Gyrus Left)|
|-42 |-6 |+30|1|0|0|IFG oper l (Inferior Frontal Gyrus, pars opercularis Left)|
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefull this works for you.  It takes a file path, reads and converts the data, then writes it out using the second function

```
from pathlib import Path
import csv
import re

def read_cluster_file(path):
    pat = re.compile(r'(\d+) voxels \((\d+)%\) covering (\d+)')
    p = Path(path)
    
    READING = False
    data = []

    for line in p.read():
        if line.startswith('Cluster'):
            # begin parsing the data
            READING = True
            x, y, z = map(int, line.split()[1:4])
            continue

        if READING and not line.strip():
            # end of data row; reset x, y, z
            READING = False

        if READING:
           try:
               v, vp, cp = map(int, pat.findall(s)[0])
               atlas = line.split('.', 1)[1]
           expect IndexError:
               print(f'With x, y, z = {x}, {y}, {z}')
               print('Could not parse line: ' + line)
               data.append(['Parse error', , , , , , ])
               continue
           row = [x, y, z, v, vp, cp, atlas]
           data.append(row)
    return data

def write_data(path, data):
    p = Path(path).with_suffix('.csv')
    with p.open('w') as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp)
        writer.writerows(data)
```

To use is:

```
path = 'C:/path/to/some/file.txt'
data = read_cluster_file(path)
write_data(path, data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. When running the code I have an error for the command expect IndexError: (invalid syntax). I was also wondering if the first variable pat in the function is not path?

Answer (score 0):

Replace file path in the below code.

```
df=[]
d={}
filepath='test.txt'
with open(filepath) as test:
    fp=test.readlines()
    for i in fp:
        if i.find('Cluster')!=-1:
            d['x']=i.split()[1]
            d['y']=i.split()[2]
            d['z']=i.split()[3]
        else:
            if len(i)<=1:
                continue
            else:
                d['voxels']=i.split()[0]
                d['voxels_pct']=i.split()[2][1:-2]
                d['covering_pct']=i.split()[4][:-1]
                d['atlas']=i[i.find('atlas.'):-2]
                df.append(d.copy())
pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: Thank you really cool. I have just an error I can't figure out how to fix for the line    d['covering_pct']=i.split()[4]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: This code works fine for the input mentioned above.
Try to print that line at which you are getting that error. If your line has any missing value then use the find() method and modify the statement. If you need further help you can post your query here.